# Volume Changing using a slider in swift 2

Tags: ios, swift, avaudioplayer, uislider

I have a `UISlider` added to my app and I am trying to figure out how to change the volume of the music playing. The music playing is being pulled from the iTunes Library using `MPMusicPlayerController`

Here is the viewDidLoad function with to show how I get the music from the iTunes Music library.

```
var musicPlayer = MPMusicPlayerController()

override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        musicPlayer = MPMusicPlayerController.systemMusicPlayer()


        //Changing the Play/Pause Button
        if musicPlayer.playbackState == MPMusicPlaybackState.Playing {

            playPauseButton.setImage(UIImage(named: "Pause"), forState: UIControlState.Normal)

            //Artwork
            let currentItem: MPMediaItem = musicPlayer.nowPlayingItem!

            let artwork: MPMediaItemArtwork = currentItem.valueForProperty(MPMediaItemPropertyArtwork) as! MPMediaItemArtwork
            let artworkImage = artwork.imageWithSize(CGSize(width: self.view.frame.width, height: 372.0))
            musicPlayerArtwork.image = artworkImage
            musicBottomBackground.image = artworkImage

            //Titel
            let titleString: String = currentItem.valueForProperty(MPMediaItemPropertyTitle) as! String
            songTitle.text = titleString as String

            //Artist & Album
            let artistString: String = currentItem.valueForProperty(MPMediaItemPropertyArtist) as! String
            let albumString: String = currentItem.valueForProperty(MPMediaItemPropertyAlbumTitle) as! String
            albumAndArtistTitle.text = "\(artistString) - \(albumString)"


        } else {

            playPauseButton.setImage(UIImage(named:  "Play"), forState: UIControlState.Normal)

        }        


    }

// I have IBAction functions linked to controlling the playbackk and pause functions that look like this one to play the music 
func startPlayMusic() {

        if self.musicPlayer.playbackState == MPMusicPlaybackState.Paused {

            self.musicPlayer.play()

        }

    }
```

I have the slider hooked up with an IBAction and IBOutlet and have the following function to attempt adjusting the volume it:

```
var audioPlayer = AVAudioPlayer()
@IBAction func volumeSliderChanging(sender: UISlider) {

        audioPlayer.volume = sender.value

    }
```

Each time I try running this and moving the slider  I get the following error

[image]

Any ideas what I could be doing wrong?

Comment: are you using CoreAnimation with this value change code?

Answer (score 1):

Your `audioPlayer` was not properly initiated. You should not call  `AVAudioPlayer()`. Refer to the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVAudioPlayerClassReference/) for list of initializers that you should use. Here's an example:

```
let url = NSBundle.mainBundle().URLForResource("mySong", withExtension: "mp3")!
self.audioPlayer = try! AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: url)
```

Comment: Thanks for this answer. My project is use the MPMusicPlayerController to play the music. Is there a way to target the song playing?

Comment: I have edited my answer to show how the music is being played.